# using rsync/cpio to backup 28TB filesystem

Tags: cpio

I need your help in finding a best tools/command to backup a huge(140k directories= 24TB) filesystem.
 I used cpio to copy 80% but my system is out of memory i was forced to kill cpio half way.
 Our system is SUSE LINUX Enterprise Server9 (ia64)
VERSION =9,PATCHLEVEL=3.32GB of Memory.

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo "++++++++++++++++ Start Date is `date`+++++++++++++ "
cd /production1/hhl_imgs
find . -depth -print | cpio -pdmv /backup1/hhl_imgs
echo "++++++++++++++++ Completion Date is `date`+++++++++"
echo "========================================================"
```

Is there a way how to find only the modified directories in /backup1/hhl_imgs of a certain date and copy them to backup directory in /backup1/hhl_imgs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at the time-related tests of find. To list all directories changed during the last day (actually, the argument to ctime is the number of 24-hour periods in scope)

```
find . -type d -ctime 1
```

if you want to establish a "point in time", try using a reference file:

```
touch -t 03071200 march-7th-noon
find . -cnewer march-7th-noon
```

depending on what time you are looking for (atime, ctime), use the respective switch to find, -atime or -anewer or the -c flavor

Comment: :thank you for your prompt reply. Suppose i want a certain date for example:March01, 2012, any directory was modified on that day should be copied to the backup. how can i do that?